# What is making the sloshing sound in the right front part of my car, under the hood?

Tags: noise

I have a 2007 chevy Malibu . It is making a sloshing sound while I am driving. It does it when I accelerate from a stop, and I have heard it when I am turning. It does not matter how long the car has been on. I do not have wet carpets in my car.
The air conditioner works a little on #3 and better on #4 and #1 &#2 speed does not do anything.

Comment: Windscreen washer bottle?

Comment: I would still bet it's your air box for the HVAC. I'd check to ensure the drain is draining.

Comment: Possibly plugged body drains in a rocker panel or door bottom...